# Hiding Ember.js debug output in Cucumber tests using Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, cucumber, poltergeist

I am currently getting this output whenever I visit a page using capybara:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.10
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the output ONLY for tests?  I am using Cucumber with the Poltergeist driver if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting

```
Ember.LOG_VERSION = false;
```

If you want this only in your test, you can could set a global variable in you test helper, and check if is set.
Another options could be, to check if QUnit is set.

```
if (!QUnit instanceof 'undefined') {
    Ember.LOG_VERSION = false;
}
```

Not tested.